What kind of apocalypse?
"I don't want to set the world on fire... I only want to tear it apart."
What kind of apocalypse (or multiple apocalypses, if necessary) would be capable of transforming the modern Earth into the setting described below?
I've been toying with the idea of making my setting a post-post apocalypse for a while now, and want to know if there's even a type of apocalypse that could make the current Earth resemble my desired setting (without so much handwaving it would be easier to just start from scratch).
Before starting, it's worth noting that the transition from modern Earth to setting Earth almost certainly involves an event like in The Novels of the Change, where some physical laws are carefully rewritten to make many technologies (notably including gunpowder, engines, and electricity) nonfunctional, and at the same time supernatural elements start appearing (notably gods). Based on this answer, that's the only practical way to kick humanity's tech level down past the Industrial Revolution, with the added bonus that some recent innovations to old technologies will still be applicable.
In case anyone wants to suggest a supernatural apocalypse, here are the rules for gods in my setting. 1) They are bound by the faith of their worshipers, and only have as much power as mortals have Faith in them. 2) They cannot act against their Legend (their believers' expectations for how they act, appear, and even speak). Similar to both Roles in A Practical Guide to Evil and Fatebinding in the Scion TTRPGs.
Required elements:

Water world. Either the seas must rise (in which case, where is the extra water coming from?), or the lands must fall, but there are no continental landmasses abovewater in the setting, just a whole lot of islands.
Some humans survive. While there are gods in the setting who can revive extinct species, their power stems directly from worship, so a decent chunk of humans have to survive to create and empower the gods.

Bonus points:

Humans survive all over the world. The more cultures make it through, the better.
Even more islands. Flooding the continents would turn all the mountain ranges into archipelagos, but even more islands being created is better.
Climate still recognizable... at least by the time the story starts, a few thousand years later.
Ecosystem survives. Some extinctions are fine, maybe even lots of extinctions, but I'm not looking for another Great Dying.

Note that all four of the bonus points can be handwaved by divine intervention (and I suspect that will be necessary for the 4th point especially), but as I said earlier, I'm looking to see what can be done without that handwave first.

(1) There is no question mark in this question. There is one in the title, but it is at the end of a purely rhetorical question. (2) There is not enough water on Earth to flood all the continental landmasses. Nowhere even near enough water. Which means that the first prime required element number one is not achievable in the real physical world; which means that I don't fully understand what this question is even about. VTC because more clarity would be very nice.

What does VTC stand for? I get the gist of the request, but I'm drawing a blank on the specific acronym.

RE: Insufficient water, I can think of two scientific ways and one fantasy way to solve that problem just off the top of my head. (Comet impacts delivering extra water, impact craters redistributing the existing land, portal to the bottom of another plane's oceans). I suppose I could expand one of those into a full answer.

"VTC" -> "vote to close"

@JBH Have you considered lobbying stackexchange to shut down Worldbuilding entirely?  It would save you and Sphennings a lot of time, rather than doing it question by question.

@Jedediah Have you considered visiting Quora, Reddit, or any of the other forums that lack the rules of both Stack Exchange and this Stack? However, I'm grateful that you've pointed out my comment. I ignored the magical/supernatural aspect of the question entirely an answere it stictly otherwise. I needed to retract my vote and comment. Cheers.

Thank you for not tagging this science-based
If I understand your question correctly, you need your water world to exist at a point of about a thousand years after said apocalypse and for however many years (less than a century?) for the story.
Excellent!
Allow me to introduce you to the HAB theory, introduced to the world (not by that name) by Hugh Auchincloss Brown in his 1967 book, Cataclysms of the Earth.
Auchincloss was an electrical engineer with a great idea. The idea has never been accepted in the more uptight scientific circles... but he has enough circumstantial evidence to make anyone with a decent imagination rub their chin and think to themselves, "hmmm...." And that makes it particularly useful for worldbuilding.
The theory suggests that when enough ice builds at the South Pole, the Earth rotates 90°. Rapidly! Auchincloss suggests his theory explains why mastodons have been found frozen so quickly that their food was still amidst their teeth as neatly as it does the many flood myths found in many cultures throughout the world.
Such rapid rotation would move equatorial lands to the poles and cause water to flood over the Earth's lands. The result not only sloshes water all over everything, but causes the now equatorial ice cap to melt — adding that much more water to the mix. When it melts enough (time must pass), the not-yet-reabsorbed original equatorial bulge forces the Earth to snap back upright.
Time aplenty for your story to take place, and change to the world aplenty to rationalize your goals. Scientifically, there isn't enough water in the south polar ice cap to flood the Earth such that all that remains is islands — but the step from the flooding that would occur and what you need for your story is within suspension of disbelief.
If we assume that the world's many flood myths and those quick-frozen mastodons indicate some planetary tragedy that we all survived, then you have manifest evidence of the practicality of this application. Humanity survived well enough to foster its great many flood myths.
And the other bonus questions?
I can't help you with the addition of many more islands. You could apply to volcanism along the world's many fault lines... but that's a hard nut to swallow, too. Of course, if you spin the world on its proverbial head so quickly, that's gotta create a bit of  rumbly tummy. So maybe the HAB theory would permit you a modest number of new volcanic islands!
But then there's the last two bullets. You just removed 95% or more of the world's exposed landmass. What climate do you expect to be unaffected? That's pure wishful thinking. Include it in your story as you will, but there isn't  rationalization for it. Changing the world needs change the climate. Flipping it on it's ear will change it, too.
And then there's the desire to save what I believe is your goal of the entire ecosystem. Same problem. The oceanic ecosystems are well protected if not mixed up a great deal. There would be some loss — even perhaps a great loss — but they'd swiftly resettle as the new equatorial warmth began to take hold. But the land-based ecosystems? You just permanently flooded 95% or more of them. I don't know what you're expecting, but I expect you'd be very disappointed.

The land masses break up.
You're probably going to have to go for divine intervention for this one, for the initial effect.  True, landmasses such as Pangaea have broken up because they served as a blanket upon the earth, and volcanic forces rose with more force there.  But for our current masses, you will have to posit divine upswelling of magma under the current ones.
This shatters the continents.  If you are happy with there being as much land in island form as now exists in continents, that's all that's needed.  If you want there to be less land, the continental shelves sometimes shatter so that land vanishes, and sometimes sink, so that only parts of the current land remain above water.

Recent news: https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/international/global-trends/scientists-find-massive-hidden-fuel-reserve-enough-to-meet-energy-needs-for-two-centuries-but-theres-a-catch/articleshow/116367556.cms
I could imagine some runaway burning of all hydrogen reserves, for example as a result of business, AI, international or military rivalry. Burning hydrogen makes water. Probably not enough to flood entire continents, but it could trigger some vicious cycle in the climate, or the mining itself could maybe unplug high pressure water reserves in Earth's mantle.

high-pressure water reserves. Nice one. Better than the hydrogen bit though I think...

There are a lot of pieces to this but one thing could make it happen. The earth is super electrified. Usually a sun spot/solar flairs would temporarily remove the the electromagnet covering on the planet but this one did the opposite, super charging it where the at time crackles with energy. Through pseudoscience and logic, we can use this to do what you want.
First, advanced tech is gone. Most gunpowder would instantly explode, and arching would happen in most electronics forcing such tech unfeasible. Some flintlock could theoretically work but the danger and wood casing needed to make them would make it impractical for repeated use.
The continents would be blown apart because of the sulfur and oil holds that have not been found and deeper in the curst, the metals expand making new tectonic plates shearing lands apart, mountains falling into the sea the icecaps melting The Romanche Trench closing. This might still not be enough to make a full water world with most island being able to see several dozen or even hundreds of islands, but it is close.
This is also the catalyst of the gods. Over the years, people have learned to channel the energy build up into another and our tolerances have increased to channel much. Some have learned to control it to a great degree to even sink island of their enemies. Some gods, after their ascension, in their heart of hearts, wish to step down, but the hopes, devotion, desires, and power force them to stay.
Other notes; most cultures would not change beside the introduction of the new gods. The climate would be more stable because the energy both warms the earth and protects it from the sun light. With this also take into consideration, we are not the only things that would be effected. Other animals might have gods, some plants, being starved from the reduction of sun light, might start growing off of the charged atmosphere.
Final note. Water will not shock you. In fact with so much energy, lightning strikes should be rare since it is the build up of positive and negative charges which should be hard to achieve.
